# Instance based date field granularity

Tags: 7, entities

In my web application (Drupal 7) I'm using a date field with year-month-day granularity, but I would like, for a specific content type, to add also hours and minutes.

1. Is this possible to achieve? How?
2. Is this safe or it'll mess with the other content types, existing views etc.?

I've thought of adding an extra time only field, so I've checked some modules like [CCK Time](https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_time) or [Timefield](https://www.drupal.org/project/timefield), but they don't seem maintained anymore (last release is about two years old).

**Use case:**
I have an "Absence" content type. When a student is absent, the teacher selects the day when the student is absent, hours and minutes aren't needed. I'm now creating an "Early exit" content type: if a students has to go out from school before the regular school day end, in that case the teacher need also the time when the student left the school. As an alternative I was thinking on two integer fields (hours and minuter), but it doesn't sound as an optimal solution to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) has the ability to add time field with the same field , I think you need to enable that in the field settings. see screenshot:[image]

Comment: Yeah, but this applies to all the content types where this field is used. I would like to add hours and minutes only to the date field in one content type, the others should remain year-moth-day

Comment: That's fine, just change the date field setting in the content type you want, it wont affect the other content types.

Comment: I tried just to be sure. It changed everywhere, not only in the content type I want. As the setting page says: "These settings apply to the Date field everywhere it is used."

Comment: Weird, I recall that I did it at some point before, worse case you could create another date field for that content type, unless you have data you want to keep.